# arraylist item cannot be applied to another list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, casting

i  have a problem with array list.  i have the following

```
 private ArrayList<?> selectedTransactionList;
  private ArrayList<?> transactionList;
```

then i am initializing like this:

```
 selectedTransactionList = new ArrayList<Income>();
 transactionList = new ArrayList<Income>();
```

with Income been a custom class with getter and setters function.
after populating the transactionList with data, i am doing this:
selectedTransactionList.add((Income)transactionList.get(1));

however, android is giving error such as: 
add (capture) in ArrayList cannot be applied
to (com.erod.finsec.Income)

iam declaring the array as ArrayList  because i have other classes that i  need to create array list. for example:

```
  selectedTransactionList = new ArrayList<Expense>();
     transactionList = new ArrayList<Expense>();
```

same code logic applies for expense and income and others and i dont want to create separate class with same code but only difference is either array list is income,expense , other type.
how can i solve erro above ?

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<?>` doesn't allow to add elements to it as you could read on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html
I suggest to change type `<?>` to `<T>` and then use generic class for that

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify ArrayList type while declaring:

```
private ArrayList<Income> selectedTransactionList;
private ArrayList<Income> transactionList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create base abstract class/interface and extend/implement this in your `Income` and `Expense` class.

You can create an interface like below

```
interface Item {
  // add common methods if required
}
```

Then simply implement this interface

```
class Income implements Item {
  // Keep rest of the code as it is
}
class Expense implements Item {
  // Keep rest of the code as it is
}
```

Then declare your list of type `Item`.

```
private List<Item> selectedTransactionList;
private List<Item> transactionList;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you want a class specifically for the common abstraction.

```
class Transactions<T> {
    private final List<?> selectedTransactionList = new ArrayList<T>();
    private final List<?> transactionList = new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

(Note, this is a case when the plural is correct.)

The code dealing specifically with `Income` uses it as:

```
Transaction<Income> transactions = new Transaction();
```

Likewise `Expense`.

```
Transaction<Expense> transactions = new Transaction();
```

If there is a common interface between `Income` and `Expense` add that as a bound to the `Transaction` class type parameter. This allows methods within `Transaction` to use methods within the common type.

```
class Transactions<T extends RelevantAccountancyTerm> {
```

Comment: hi Tom, thanks for  your answer but i am getting error message when i try something like transactions.clear()   ,   transactions.add(Income).  the error is: cannot resolve symbol clear()  and cannot resolve symbol add(income).  how can i fix it so that i can use all the arraylist method